# How to change global variable with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures, alamofire

I want to get user data with Alamofire and populate it to tableView.

**My code:**

```
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var userEntries = [UserEntries]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchUserData { (ue) in
            print("ue.count is: \(ue.count)")
            self.userEntries = ue
            print("self.userEntries.count in this block: \(self.userEntries.count)")
        }

        print("self.userEntries.count in viewDidLoad is: \(self.userEntries.count)")
    }

    func fetchUserData(completion: @escaping ([UserEntries]) -> Void) {
        //another code...

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let data = json["mydata"][0].array
                var userEntries = [UserEntries]()
                //I have 2 records only        
                data?.forEach({ (p) in
                    userEntries.append(UserEntries(id: p["id"].stringValue, date: p["date"].stringValue, text: p["text"].stringValue))
                })
                completion(userEntries)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userEntries.count //it is return 0...
    }
}
```

In the viewDidLoad I have this prints:

> self.userEntries.count in viewDidLoad is: 0 //it must be 2!!!
>
> ue.count is: 2
>
> self.userEntries.count in this block: 2

And in numberOfRowsInSection method return 0, because

> self.userEntries.count in viewDidLoad is: 0 //it must be 2!!!

How to correctly set 'self.userEntries' variable (array) for use it in tableView methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the table inside the completion as the call to get data is asynchronous

```
fetchUserData { (ue) in
   print("ue.count is: \(ue.count)")
   self.userEntries = ue
   print("self.userEntries.count in this block: \(self.userEntries.count)")
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```